# If $A=(1,2,3,4,5,6)$, prove that A=(1,6)(1,5)(1,4)(1,3)(1,2).

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $A=(1,2,3,4,5,6)$, prove that $A=(1,6)(1,5)(1,4)(1,3)(1,2)$.

Comment: Where are you stuck ! if $n\in \{1,...,6\}$, compute $(1...6)n$ and $(16)(15)(14)(13)(12)n$ and compare them ;-)

Comment: Every $k$-cycle is a product of no less than $k−1$ transpositions. In particular,for a $k$-cycle $(i_1,i_2,\cdots ,i_k)\in S_n$, we have $(i_1,i_2,\cdots ,i_k)=(i_1,i_k)(i_1,i_{k−1}) \cdots (i_1,i_2).$ @JeanMarie.

Comment: @s1simple : You are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A=(1,6)(1,5)(1,4)(1,3)(1,2)=(1,6)(1,5)(1,4)(1,2,3)=(1,6)(1,5)(1,2,3,4)=(1,6)(1,2,3,4,5)=(1,2,3,4,5,6).$

Every $k$-cycle is a product of no less than $k−1$ transpositions. In particular,for a $k$-cycle $(i_1,i_2,\cdots ,i_k)\in S_n$, we have $(i_1,i_2,\cdots ,i_k)=(i_1,i_k)(i_1,i_{k−1}) \cdots (i_1,i_2).$

Comment: Thank you so much. You are amazing.